# How to handle data from json with handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the next problem, I need to get some information when my html load. That information comes from an api rest so I have an ajax function that do that and the html.
I didn't find other way than putting the handlebars tags inside the script and then adding the div that is appended.

Is the another way?

```
$(document).ready(

  function obtenerProperties(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/property?type=URL",
     success: function(data){

      var source = $("#properties-template").html();

      var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

     $(".prueba").append(template(data));

     },
      error: function(data) {
      console.log('error', data);
      }
   })
   }

 );
```

HTML:

```
     <body>
    <script id="properties-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                        <th scope="col">Cron</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        {{#each properties}}
                    <tr>

                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td>{{clave}}</td>
                        <td>{{valor}}</td>
                        {{/each}}
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
  </script>
  <div class="prueba">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer, I put the `$ajax` call in a separate script tab within the html body and moved the `pruba` class to `tbody'.

```
 `<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(
  function obtenerProperties(){
   $.ajax({
 url: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/property?type=URL",
 success: function(data){
  var source = $("#properties-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
 $(".prueba").append(template(data));
 },
  error: function(data) {
  console.log('error', data);
  }
 })
});
</script>
<script id="properties-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"/>
    <div class="">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Cron</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="prueba">
                    {{#each properties}}                   
                    {{data}}                      
                    {{/each}}                  
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>`
```

Comment: I would like to find a way to put all the html code inside the "prueba" div or inside the script without having that div "prueba", could be that possible?

Comment: What does that cless do?

Comment: Now it's only purpose is to allow me to see what's inside the script tag, if I delete it I see nothing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why do you want to put everything in the script tag?

Comment: By the contrary my intention is to put everything in the div tag

Comment: I think I understand. In my newly edited answer, I put the `$ajax` call in a separate script tab within the html body and moved the `pruba` class to `tbody'.  Feel like giving it a try?